# Logging activity traces with custom APIs

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I've got this idea (based on experience) that logging plain messages isn't just enough to monitor an application so I built an abstraction layer on top of the built-in `logging` package.

---

**NOTE**: I have refactored virtually the entire previous code as I wasn't happy with it at all.

---

Basiacally what it does, is to automatically log the `begin` and `end` of an *activity*. An activity is usually a function, but can be also a custom scope. This allows me to quickly find out whether something worked or if not then how it *failed* and whether it actually started.

#### Example:

```py
@wiretap.telemetry()
def example():
    pass
```

> 2023-10-25 11:38:02.710 _ example | begin | 0.000s | None | {'source': {'file': 'demo.py', 'line': 173}} | None
> 2023-10-25 11:38:02.723 _ example | end | 0.012s | None | {} | None

Where the formatter's pattern is defined as:

> ```
> "fmt": "{asctime}.{msecs:03.0f} {indent} {activity} | {trace} | {elapsed:.3f}s | {message} | {details} | {attachment}"
> ```

Other examples:

```py
@wiretap.telemetry(include_args=True, include_result=True, alias="example2")
def example(x: int, y: int):
    return x +  y

@wiretap.telemetry(auto_begin=False, include_result=True)
def example(x: int, y: int, activity: wiretap.Activity = None):
    activity.initial.trace_begin().with_message("This is the begin!").with_details(x=x).log()
    return x +  y
```

---

#### Theory

The package (I call it *wiretap*) extends the `LogRecord` with such extras as:

- `parent_id` - optional `UUID` of the parent logger (this is the correlation-id of the parent activity)
- `unique_id` - `UUID` of the current logger (this is the correlation-id; always the same for a single activity)
- `timestamp` - date/time
- `activity` - the name of the activity (function or alias)
- `level` - the log-level
- `trace` - the name of the trace that an activity leaves
- `elapsed` - time in seconds elapsed since the logger has started
- `details` - json-details about the activity (args, source, result etc)
- `attachment` - blob/text to dump any additional data
- `indent` - used only for console or file indicates the depth of the activity by injecting that number of `_` or some other user specified character.

---

Each activity must leave at least two *traces*: `begin` & `end` indicating that everything went as planned. The `end` can be replaced by:

- `error` - something unexptected occured
- `noop` - no-op meaning an activity didn't have to do anything (like removing columns from a `DataFrame` that already doesn't have the columns to remove)
- `abort` - an activity couldn't do it's job due to some precondition not being met (like filtering a `DataFrame` that's empty)

---

`begin` & `end` can be logged only **once**, but between them other traces can provide any number of additional debug information about an activity:

- `info` - arbitrary data
- `item` - info about one of many items being processed (like in a loop)
- `skip` - info about an item being skipped (like in a loop)
- `metric` - numeric info about some measurements

---

#### Implementation

The implementation is covered by the `Activity` class that internally redirects all calls to the `logging` package via the `.log` API. It has three attributes that groups traces into categories:

- `start` - logs the beginning of an activity
- `other` - logs other things
- `final` - logs the final trace

Each of the three helpers contains methods to create a `Trace` of that type that can be further customized and finally logged with its specialized `log` methods that make sure that each trace is used properly. The start and final traces are allowed only once and logging any trace but the beginning one requires the beginning one to already be logged.

```py
import contextlib
import dataclasses
import inspect
import logging
import re
from contextvars import ContextVar
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Callable, Any, Protocol, Iterator

from ..tools import Elapsed, Node
from .trace import Trace


class NewTrace(Protocol):
    def __call__(self, name: str | None = None) -> Trace: ...


OnError = Callable[[BaseException, "Activity"], None]
OnBegin = Callable[[Trace], Trace]

current_activity: ContextVar[Node["Activity"] | None] = ContextVar("current_activity", default=None)


class Activity:
    """
    This class represents an activity for which telemetry is collected.
    """

    def __init__(
            self,
            name: str,
            file: str,
            line: int,
            auto_begin: bool = True,
            on_begin: OnBegin | None = None,
            on_error: OnError | None = None
    ):
        self.name = name
        self.file = file
        self.line = line
        self.elapsed = Elapsed()

        self._auto_begin = auto_begin
        self._on_begin = on_begin or (lambda _t: _t)
        self._on_error = on_error or (lambda _exc, _logger: None)
        self._logger = logging.getLogger(name)
        self._started = ActivityStartLogged(name, file, line)
        self._tracing = PendingTrace(name, file, line)
        self._finalized = OneTimeFalse()

        self.start = StartTrace(self._trace(self._log_start))
        self.other = OtherTrace(self._trace(self._log_other))
        self.final = FinalTrace(self._trace(self._log_final))

    def _log(self, trace: Trace) -> None:
        self._logger.log(
            level=trace.level,
            msg=trace.message,
            exc_info=trace.exc_info,
            extra=dict(
                activity=self.name,
                trace=trace.name,
                elapsed=float(self.elapsed),
                details=trace.details,
                attachment=trace.attachment
            )
        )

    # This is how start traces are logged.
    def _log_start(self, trace: Trace):
        self._tracing.clear()
        self._started.yes_for(trace.name)
        # Source info is logged only here.
        self._log(trace.with_details(source=dict(file=self.file, line=self.line)))

    # This is how other traces are logged.
    def _log_other(self, trace: Trace):
        self._tracing.clear()
        self._started.require_for(trace.name)
        self._log(trace)

    # This is how final traces are logged.
    def _log_final(self, trace: Trace):
        self._tracing.clear()
        # Makes sure that final traces aren't logged multiple times.
        # This can happen when an error trace was logged, so the end trace is obsolete.
        if self._finalized:
            return
        self._started.require_for(trace.name)
        self._log(trace)

    # Creates a factory function for the Trace as some additional work is necessary.
    def _trace(self, log: Callable[[Trace], None]) -> NewTrace:
        def _factory(name: str | None = None) -> Trace:
            name = name or str(TraceNameByCaller(2))
            self._tracing.register(name)
            return Trace(name, log)

        return _factory

    def __enter__(self) -> "Activity":
        parent = current_activity.get()
        self._token = current_activity.set(Node(self, parent))
        if self._auto_begin:
            self.start.trace_begin().action(self._on_begin).log()
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        if exc_val:
            if isinstance(exc_val, (ActivityStartMissing, ActivityAlreadyStarted, PreviousTraceNotLogged)):
                # Do nothing when these errors occur, otherwise the same exception will raise for the default handler.
                pass
            else:
                self._on_error(exc_val, self)
                self.final.trace_error(f"Unhandled <{exc_type.__name__}> has occurred: <{str(exc_val) or 'N/A'}>").log()
        else:
            self.final.trace_end().log()

        current_activity.reset(self._token)
        return False


@contextlib.contextmanager
def begin_activity(
        name: str,
        auto_begin=True,
        on_begin: OnBegin | None = None,
        on_error: OnError | None = None
) -> Iterator[Activity]:
    stack = inspect.stack()
    frame = stack[2]
    with Activity(
            name=name,
            file=Path(frame.filename).name,
            line=frame.lineno,
            auto_begin=auto_begin,
            on_begin=on_begin,
            on_error=on_error
    ) as activity:
        yield activity


@dataclasses.dataclass(frozen=True, slots=True)
class LogAbortWhen(OnError):
    exceptions: type[BaseException] | tuple[type[BaseException], ...]

    def __call__(self, exc: BaseException, activity: Activity) -> None:
        if isinstance(exc, self.exceptions):
            activity.final.trace_abort(f"Unable to complete due to <{type(exc).__name__}>: {str(exc) or '<N/A>'}").log()


class StartTrace:
    def __init__(self, trace: NewTrace):
        self._trace = trace

    def trace(self, name: str) -> Trace:
        return self._trace(name).as_info()

    def trace_begin(self) -> Trace:
        return self._trace().as_info()


class OtherTrace:
    def __init__(self, trace: NewTrace):
        self._trace = trace

    def trace(self, name: str) -> Trace:
        return self._trace(name).as_debug()

    def trace_info(self, message: str) -> Trace:
        return self._trace().with_message(message).as_debug()

    def trace_item(self, name: str, value: Any) -> Trace:
        return self._trace().with_details(**{name: value}).as_debug()

    def trace_skip(self, message: str) -> Trace:
        return self._trace().with_message(message).as_debug()

    def trace_metric(self, name: str, value: Any) -> Trace:
        return self._trace().with_details(**{name: value}).as_debug()


class FinalTrace:
    def __init__(self, trace: NewTrace):
        self._trace = trace

    def trace(self, name: str) -> Trace:
        return self._trace(name).as_info()

    def trace_noop(self, message: str) -> Trace:
        return self._trace().with_message(message).as_info()

    def trace_abort(self, message: str) -> Trace:
        return self._trace().with_message(message).as_warning()

    def trace_error(self, message: str) -> Trace:
        return self._trace().with_message(message).as_error().with_exc_info(True)

    def trace_end(self) -> Trace:
        return self._trace().as_info()


class OneTimeFalse:
    state = False

    def __bool__(self):
        try:
            return self.state
        finally:
            self.state = True


class TraceNameByCaller:

    def __init__(self, frame_index: int):
        caller = inspect.stack()[frame_index].function
        self.value = re.sub("^trace_", "", caller, flags=re.IGNORECASE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.value


class ActivityAlreadyStarted(Exception):
    def __init__(self, activity: str, file: str, line: int, trace: str):
        super().__init__(
            f"Cannot trace <{trace}> for the <{activity}> activity in <{file}:{line}>. "
            f"You already did that. Did you mean to disable <auto_begin>?"
        )


class ActivityStartMissing(Exception):
    def __init__(self, activity: str, file: str, line: int, trace: str):
        super().__init__(
            f"Cannot trace <{trace}> for the <{activity}> activity in <{file}:{line}>. "
            f"You need to log an start trace first."
        )


@dataclasses.dataclass
class ActivityStartLogged:
    """
    This class provides a mechanism to ensure that an initial trace is logged before any other trace is.
    This situation may occur when telemetry's auto_begin=True and the user forgets to call logger.initial.log_begin.
    """
    name: str
    file: str
    line: int
    _value = False

    def yes_for(self, trace: str):
        if self:
            raise ActivityAlreadyStarted(self.name, self.file, self.line, trace)
        self._value = True

    def require_for(self, trace: str):
        if not self:
            raise ActivityStartMissing(self.name, self.file, self.line, trace)

    def __bool__(self) -> bool:
        return self._value


class PreviousTraceNotLogged(Exception):
    def __init__(self, activity: str, file: str, line: int, trace: str, previous: str):
        super().__init__(
            f"Cannot create or log trace <{trace}> for the <{activity}> activity in <{file}:{line}>. "
            f"You need to log the previous <{previous}> trace first."
        )


class PendingTrace:
    """
    This class helps to make sure that pending traces are logged before the next one.
    """

    def __init__(self, activity: str, file: str, line: int):
        self.activity = activity
        self.file = file
        self.line = line
        self.name: str | None = None

    def register(self, name: str):
        if self.name:
            raise PreviousTraceNotLogged(self.activity, self.file, self.line, trace=name, previous=self.name)
        self.name = name

    def clear(self):
        self.name = None
```

The `Trace` class is a builder for a trace:

```py
import logging
from typing import Any, Callable

from ..specs import ExcInfo


class Trace:
    """
    This class is a builder for a single activity trace.
    The process ends when log() is called and the trace is sent to the log.
    """

    def __init__(self, name: str, log: Callable[["Trace"], None] | None):
        self.name = name
        self.message: str | None = None
        self.details: dict[str, Any] = {}
        self.attachment: Any | None = None
        self.level: int = logging.INFO
        self.exc_info: ExcInfo | bool | None = None
        self.extra: dict[str, Any] = {}
        self._log = log or (lambda _: None)

    def with_message(self, value: str | None) -> "Trace":
        self.message = value
        return self

    def with_details(self, **kwargs) -> "Trace":
        self.details = self.details | kwargs
        return self

    def with_attachment(self, value: Any) -> "Trace":
        self.attachment = value
        return self

    def with_exc_info(self, value: ExcInfo | bool) -> "Trace":
        self.exc_info = value
        return self

    def with_level(self, value: int) -> "Trace":
        self.level = value
        return self

    def as_debug(self) -> "Trace":
        self.level = logging.DEBUG
        return self

    def as_info(self) -> "Trace":
        self.level = logging.INFO
        return self

    def as_warning(self) -> "Trace":
        self.level = logging.WARNING
        return self

    def as_error(self) -> "Trace":
        self.level = logging.ERROR
        return self

    def action(self, func: Callable[["Trace"], "Trace"]) -> "Trace":
        return func(self)

    def log(self):
        self._log(self)
```

---

The final core component is the `telemetry` decorator. It initializes the `Activity` and can pass it via dependency-injection to the decorated method if specified as `activity: wiretap.Activity = None`. It should also be able to handle `async` methods, thus the *double* implementation.

```py
import asyncio
import functools
import inspect
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Any, Callable, TypeVar, Generic

from .tracing import Activity, OnBegin, OnError


def telemetry(
        alias: str | None = None,
        include_args: dict[str, str | Callable | None] | bool | None = False,
        include_result: str | Callable | bool | None = False,
        auto_begin=True,
        on_begin: OnBegin | None = None,
        on_error: OnError | None = None
):
    """Provides telemetry for the decorated function."""

    on_begin = on_begin or (lambda _t: _t)
    on_error = on_error or (lambda _exc, _logger: None)

    def factory(decoratee):
        stack = inspect.stack()
        frame = stack[1]
        kwargs_with_activity = KwargsWithActivity(decoratee)

        def activity(**kwargs) -> Activity:
            """
            Creates an activity with args to format because they are known later when the decorator is called.
            """
            return Activity(
                name=alias or decoratee.__name__,
                file=Path(frame.filename).name,
                line=frame.lineno,
                auto_begin=auto_begin,
                on_begin=lambda t: t.action(on_begin).with_details(**kwargs),
                on_error=on_error
            )

        if asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(decoratee):
            @functools.wraps(decoratee)
            async def decorator(*decoratee_args, **decoratee_kwargs):
                args = get_args(decoratee, *decoratee_args, **decoratee_kwargs)
                with activity(args_native=args, args_format=include_args) as act:
                    result = await decoratee(*decoratee_args, **kwargs_with_activity(decoratee_kwargs, act))
                    act.final.trace_end().with_details(result_native=result, result_format=include_result).log()
                    return result

            decorator.__signature__ = inspect.signature(decoratee)
            return decorator

        else:
            @functools.wraps(decoratee)
            def decorator(*decoratee_args, **decoratee_kwargs):
                args = get_args(decoratee, *decoratee_args, **decoratee_kwargs)
                with activity(args_native=args, args_format=include_args) as act:
                    result = decoratee(*decoratee_args, **kwargs_with_activity(decoratee_kwargs, act))
                    act.final.trace_end().with_details(result_native=result, result_format=include_result).log()
                    return result

            decorator.__signature__ = inspect.signature(decoratee)
            return decorator

    return factory


_Func = TypeVar("_Func", bound=Callable)


class KwargsWithActivity(Generic[_Func]):
    """
    This tool finds the parameter of type Activity and injects the instance of it.
    """
    def __init__(self, func: _Func):
        # Find the name of the activity argument if any...
        self.name = next((n for n, t in inspect.getfullargspec(func).annotations.items() if t is Activity), "")

    def __call__(self, kwargs: dict[str, Any], activity: Activity) -> dict[str, Any]:
        # If name exists, then the key definitely is there so no need to check twice.
        if self.name:
            kwargs[self.name] = activity
        return kwargs


def get_args(decoratee: object, *args, **kwargs) -> dict[str, Any]:
    # Zip arg names and their indexes up to the number of args of the decoratee_args.
    arg_pairs = zip(inspect.getfullargspec(decoratee).args, range(len(args)))
    # Turn arg_pairs into a dictionary and combine it with decoratee_kwargs.
    return {t[0]: args[t[1]] for t in arg_pairs} | kwargs
```

---

There are three more components used here that support the `Elapsed` time, `Used` for the single-used trace and `TraceNameByCaller` to get the name of the calling function automatically.

```py
from timeit import default_timer as timer


class Elapsed:
    _start: float | None = None

    @property
    def current(self) -> float:
        """Gets the current elapsed time in seconds or 0 if called for the first time."""
        if self._start:
            return timer() - self._start
        else:
            self._start = timer()
            return .0

    def __float__(self):
        return self.current


class Used:
    state = False

    def __bool__(self):
        try:
            return self.state
        finally:
            self.state = True


class TraceNameByCaller:

    def __init__(self):
        caller = inspect.stack()[1][3]
        self.value = re.sub("^log_", "", caller, flags=re.IGNORECASE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.value
```

Oh, there's one more class... the `Node` that tracks the hierarchy of the activities:

```py
_T = TypeVar("_T")


@dataclasses.dataclass(frozen=True, slots=True)
class Node(Generic[_T]):
    value: _T
    parent: Optional["Node[_T]"]
    id: uuid.UUID = uuid.uuid4()

    @property
    def depth(self) -> int:
        return self.parent.depth + 1 if self.parent else 1

    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator["Node"]:
        current: Node[_T] | None = self
        while current:
            yield current
            current = current.parent
```

---

#### Review

Apart from this code, there are only a couple of custom `logging.Filter`s that customize the `LogRecord`.

What do you think? Is this code fine or do you think something could be improved dramatically?

---

The full code is avilable [here](https://github.com/he-dev/wiretap-py/tree/version/7.1/wiretap/src/wiretap) on GitHub.

Comment: I'll try to write a detailed review tonight, but a few moments noticed from quick glance on repo: don't call your package or subpackage of any depth `types` - it shadows quite important standard library `types` module. Add at least some CI format-test-deploy pipeline (can suggest pre-commit for the lint step). You have type annotations, but `mypy` is not green - it's about CI again. Please wrap code lines (`black` can do this for you) - 100+ char/line is almost unreadable, esp. in complex editor setup with 2-3 panels stacked horizontally. I mean, even github page needs horiz. scrolling...

Comment: @SUTerliakov I tried to make `mypy` happy, but that's the best I can do ;-] About long lines. Their actually an exception here as they're pretty much all the same and I don't like _random_ line breaks so I instructed `PyCharm` to not interfere and set it to 500 heh. Either all params are each on a new line or none. There are no partial line-breaks with me ;P With these couple of APIs I chose to go with lengthy ones.

Comment: @SUTerliakov "don't call your package or subpackage of any depth types - it shadows quite important standard library types module." Please note [PEP 328](https://peps.python.org/pep-0328/#rationale-for-absolute-imports) resolved the issue. You can see [`from . import types`](https://github.com/he-dev/wiretap-py/blob/fbde96e6e2065b8bf541c54100b334698592f24b/wiretap/src/wiretap/__init__.py#L4C1-L5C1), a relative import, so `wiretap.types` cannot shadow `types`.

Comment: @Peilonrayz no, not really: it resolves only "production" case where package root is not in PATH. During development it can often be the case (e.g. I usually have package root open when debugging something to save some typing in commands, so it's CWD and `./types` overrides builtin `types` for absolute import).

Comment: @SUTerliakov Sounds like [a workflow issue](https://xkcd.com/1172/).

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for the theory-of-operation, that was a helpful introduction.

First impression from it was that, out of {message, details, attachment},
maybe we could delete one or two of them?
And rely on a JSON attribute to represent it, when present in a log entry?

I appreciate the consistent `elapsed` column, even when BEGIN makes it zero.
I could definitely see myself using `sort -n -k ...` to pick out slow operations.
You have a very clear record format.

Maybe the motivation behind `attachment` is for logging big text, like an email?
In which case I'm going to propose sacrilege: intersperse such text with log records.
We can easily use `grep "^2023-"` to pick out structured records (or even "^2").
Log `attachment` lines with some distinctive prefix, perhaps just SPACE.
Anything that doesn't start with "2" would work.
Now we have a log stream and an attachment stream interspersed on stdout,
and we can separate them, and can recover the original attachment
by stripping the initial prefix.
Just a thought.

---

## anonymous trace

```
class NewTrace(Protocol):
    def __call__(self, name: str | None = None) -> Trace: ...
```

It's not obvious to me why `name=None` would be Good.

If you were "trying to make mypy happy", consider revisiting this detail.

OIC, `trace_begin` preferred `None` over the empty string or a sentinel.
Still not exactly following why.
Maybe default to `__name__`?
Or inspect what's on the call stack to find a function name?

Hmmm, as I read through more code I think the trouble with my understanding
is I'm not yet getting what's good about calling `.clear()`.
I bet the code is great,
and the thing we might improve is the introductory documentation.

I'm not sure if `.with_message(None)` relates to the same issue or not,
but I'm surprised it doesn't insist on being passed a `str` message.

---

## BaseException

```
OnError = Callable[[BaseException, "Activity"], None]
```

Sorry, I'm not following why you needed that.
Possibly for GeneratorExit?

When developers start messing around with KeyboardInterrupt and SystemExit
it makes me nervous.
I'm willing to believe there's a good reason for not using Exception here.
Please write it down. In a """docstring""".

Similarly down in `LogAbortWhen`.
IDK, maybe we really *do* need to log `quit()` / `sys.exit()` ?
Just offer a hint about such a use case.

In the `Activity` constructor args,
kudos on making many of your attributes `_private`.
And the `or` defaulting is very nice.

---

## nice comment

Usually I grumble about too many comments,
or that they're about the "how",
or about comments that are inaccurate.
And then we come to this...

```
    # Do nothing when these errors occur, otherwise the same exception will raise for the default handler.
    pass
```

Thank you for this helpful explanation.

---

## magic number

Ok, I gave you a pass the first time, feeling it was "obvious":

```
    def _trace(...
            name = name or str(TraceNameByCaller(2))
```

And besides, if a refactor introduced one more level on the call stack
so we need `3`, I assume automated unit tests would immediately blow up
alerting us to the needed edit.

But now I see this and I start to get slightly nervous:

```
def begin_activity(
    ...
    frame = stack[2]
```

Not sure if that's the *same* `2` or not.
I'm not saying there's anything urgent to attend to here,
just encouraging you to think about it.
I worry there might be shallow + deep call paths to get here.

In contrast, down in telemetry `factory` the `stack[1]` is cool
because I can see, without scrolling, everything that could affect it.

---

## severity level

```
class OtherTrace:
    ...
    def trace_info( ...
        return self._trace().with_message(message).as_debug()
```

Not `.as_info()` ?

Sure, I get it, that's fine.
Just registering some slight
[surprise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

`trace_skip` (and perhaps "_metric") seems a little bit redundant.
Maybe its special "value add" would be to simply prepend `"skip "`
to the `message`?
Or maybe there's something planned for it in the roadmap,
which we'd like to mention in a docstring? To give guidance
to an app developer about which one is appropriate to call.

---

## vague name

In `ActivityStartLogged`, `_value` is a bit vague.
Consider renaming to `_initialized` (or `_is_initialized`).

---

## meaningful identifier

```
def get_args( ...
    return {t[0]: args[t[1]] for t in arg_pairs} | ...
```

Prefer tuple unpack over `[0]` / `[1]` indices:

```
    return {arg: args[i] for arg, i in arg_pairs} | ...
```

---

This impresses me as a well-engineered module with the details
carefully thought out.
Code formatting was easy to read, with no 500-char lines.
I appreciate the `mypy` linting, it is helpful to the Gentle Reader
and instills confidence in code correctness.

This codebase achieves its design goals and appears ready for a pypi release.

I would be willing to delegate or accept maintenance tasks on it.

Comment: I need to try harder to write more comments! I've recently opened an older project where I commented a couple of tricky lines in the past and it was such a good feeling not have to reverse engineer that thing LOL I like all the other suggestions too! Btw, I've been refactoring this code for weeks dozens of times haha and this is the first version that I'm actually happy with.

Comment: About the `attachment`. Your guess is correct. It's supposed to store some text like requests or respones etc, but only when logged into a database where all these properties actually make sense as there they can be easily queried.